# How truecaller manages call history in ios app as there is no api is given by Apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

I have gone through one of the stack over flow question , in that i am getting below answer.
First of all Apple officially does not expose any public API to access the call log. That means you can hack all you want to access the call log(Using private API's) but when submitting your app to Apple by sure it will be rejected.

Regarding the app you have mentioned(quickRemainder)

It gets the call log using a cvs file or a text file. It is not taking the info via device calllog db.

Extract from their app description.

You can import text or cvs files containing phone calls into this app.
**TrueCaller does not get the call log they just use the app to search the contacts and update the contacts with info they got. They are not reading the callogs**

now my question is regarding this answer

TrueCaller use app to search the contacts and update contacts but,if any one have idea regarding this please Help me out.
Which app TrueCaller uses to search and update on which bases it searches incoming , outgoing,missed and dial call.

I want more detail information to manage call history in ios app without apple developer rejection.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know will it help or not but you can check this link. https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/ Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Thanks ChintaN for reply,    but yes i have gone through this details but this is not allowed in current iOS deployment target 8.0 or letter so we can not use this in current latest application

Comment: @puja: TrueCaller is not reading iOS call history. I wish I could explain it as answer !